Why is the BIOS .BIN file too large for BIOS chip using CH341 programmer?
I have an old Toshiba Pro L300 laptop from pre 2010 and is mothers so need to fix for Christmas for her. BIOS is corrupted and Display wont come on so I want to erase and reprogram the BIOS after converting the .EXE file to .BIN.
But the BIOS chip is 8Mbits which is 1MB only.
After conversion to .BIN through CMD, .BIN is 1.62Mb and original .EXE file I think was 4.5Mb, so I assume if you can do update from Windows or BIOS using USB flash drive, it somehow converts and squeezes the data into the small 1Mb Bios chip?
I cant get the laptop fully started to do this and have to reprogram the chip manually but the .BIN file is too big and the programmer warns me of this.
Any solution to this as I don't know if you can compress binary data?

Having you asked the programmer for a solution?  You may be able to use a 2MB prom

Hi, not sure what you are asking me. The "programmer' is the little device that cant offer advice and the User manual for the Laptop shows only bios available are all around 1Mb so cant put a 2MB bios chip on the laptop as it wouldnt work. Do you know a way of doing this finding a compatible larger bios chip?

If the chip only has 1MB of storage, you have a file you wish to use, which is 1.62MB. Your file is not designed to program the chip you want to program.

Using 7zip, theres a file inside that 1.6 EXE called Insydeflash.exe  which is less than 1mb. Is this the raw Bios file i need and convert it to a .bin file for the CH341 programmer?

If you want, you could look at the download and see if theres a file inside that i need that is less than 1mb.        https://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BIOS/Toshiba/Toshiba-Satellite-Pro-L300-BIOS-150.shtml
